ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch' on AWS Batch GPU instance
I have a job that runs on AWS Batch on a GPU instance, my application uses torch, i.e.
import torch

The Compute Environment has only one GPU instance, I was able to confirm that torch is available there by connecting to the instance via AWS Console and ran:
sh-4.2$ python3
Python 3.7.16 (default, Aug 30 2023, 20:37:53)
[GCC 7.3.1 20180712 (Red Hat 7.3.1-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> print(torch.__version__)
1.13.1+cu117
>>>

However when I submit my Batch job, it fails saying
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

I looked into this and found that:
My AWS Batch job definition has this Command:
  CoolGPUJobDefinition:
    DependsOn: ComputeRole
    Type: AWS::Batch::JobDefinition
    Properties:
      Type: container
      ContainerProperties:
        Command:
          - "/opt/prod/bin/python3"
          - "/opt/prod/bin/start.py"

From the stacktrace of my application, it shows:
File "/opt/prod/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cool_service/slowfast/utils/distributed.py", line 9, in <module>
import torch
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'

But when I tried to ls -a in the /opt directory of this GPU instance, it didn't even have prod:
sh-4.2$ pwd
/opt
sh-4.2$ ls -a
.  ..  aws  containerd  nvidia

Somehow there's a disconnect from what I can see in the GPU instance and how AWS Batch runs my application on this GPU instance.
I'd like to understand:

Why this disconnect/discrepancy?
How could I resolve this module not found error in this case?

Thanks!

I figured this out:

The discrepancy was because my application was built into a docker image with all necessary dependencies, not really directly being run on the GPU instance, to see if torch is installed in the docker image, I needed to keep the app running (so the docker instance is up and I can enter), using this command to enter into the docker docker exec -it container_id /bin/sh and then run commands there to see if torch is installed;
To install torch module, instead of doing so via UserData in my .yaml template which is used to install/run on the GPU instance, I should be packaging torch into my docker image instead;

Just in case if anyone else runs into this issue in the future, they might find this post somewhat helpful;
Thanks
